# How to unbind `C--` from being the shortcut for scaling font size (`text-scale-decrease`)

Tags: key-bindings, prelude

The org manual states:

```
To mark a task with a repeater as DONE, use {{{kbd(C-- 1 C-c C-t)}}},
i.e., ~org-todo~ with a numeric prefix argument of =-1=.
```

However, I can't manage to do this as my `C--` is bound to `text-scale-decrease`:

```
C-- runs the command text-scale-decrease (found in global-map), which is an autoloaded interactive compiled
Lisp function in ‘face-remap.el’.

It is bound to C--.
```

How to dissociate them?

Comment: This isn't really about Org mode. `C--` is a global binding for providing a specific kind of prefix argument. Apparently Prelude just wipes that out willy nilly (?).

Comment: Not to excuse Prelude's behavior of course, but there *are* other ways of giving a -1 argument to `org-todo`, e.g. `M--1 C-c C-t` or `C-u -1 C-c C-t`.

Comment: @NickD: Yes, and the multiple default bindings exist for a reason. Users can change any bindings. So can 3rd-party libraries (nothing prevents them), but this isn't a great idea. IMO - not so polite/considerate. But of course using Prelude is optional, so there's no real imposition.

Answer (score 1):

It was defined in `prelude-global-keybindings.el`, so I commented this line. It would be nice to know how to override this without having to alter the prelude files themselves.

Comment: I wonder *why* Prelude overrides that important global default binding for `C--`. That should be a no-no. I think it should be added as a suggested guideline in (elisp) [Key Binding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html), along with the guidelines to not bind `C-h` and `C-g`. (*Users*, of course, can bind and rebind any keys they like.)